# ActiveRecord MySQL query "Like" from self and associations retrieves null if associations are non existant

Tags: mysql, activerecord, associations

I have the following scope:

```
 scope :scope_name_or_email_search, lambda { |query = ''|
    joins(:user_information)
      .where('
        users.email LIKE ? OR
        user_informations.first_name LIKE ? OR
        user_informations.last_name LIKE ?',
             "%#{query}%", "%#{query}%", "%#{query}%")
  }
```

This scope is retrieving only users with "user_informations" data.
If i search for "@" only the users with "user_informations" data are retrieved however all of them have the character "@" on their emails.

What would be the best approach?

Comment: You need to use a left join if you want to include users with no `user_information`.

Comment: Alternatively you can use a UNION: Combine a query of just `users` that searches for matching `email`, with a query that joins `users` with `user_information` and searches for matching `first_name` or `last_name`.

Comment: hey alphabetus, if you got your solution, can you post it as an answer so its helpful to others

Comment: @trh indeed i have. Incoming.

Comment: @Barmar i was deep on code. Indeed the right solution. You should post this i will move the right answer to you. Cheers.

Comment: @trh answer is posted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is quite simple. I need a join left on the query, so the ActiveRecord scope would become this:

```
scope :scope_name_or_email_search, lambda { |query = ''|
    left_joins(:user_information)
      .where('
        users.email LIKE ? OR
        user_informations.first_name LIKE ? OR
        user_informations.last_name LIKE ?',
             "%#{query}%", "%#{query}%", "%#{query}%")
  }
```